# How can I quickly access the Matlab help from within Vim?

Tags: matlab, vim

When using the Matlab interface I can access the help for a function by using `help function`
or by pressing F1 while the cursor is on the function name.

Is it possible to access the Matlab help files from within Vim? An other possibility may be to convert Matlab function help to a Vim helpfile and use `:help function`

Comment: Which format is the Matlab help? Can it be launched (to a particular topic) from the command-line?!

Comment: I think for most functions it is the first comment section within the function file which is then parsed for help display. How the help for toolboxes and folders is generated I don't know.

Comment: Toolboxes and folders help is in a file called `Contents.m` - but I think the way to go would be to execute `help` in the Matlab process.

Comment: If you can answer @IngoKarkat's question, then you should be able to use the `K` command.  See `:help K` and `:help 'kp'`.

Comment: There are two types of help texts in Matlab, those in the first comment in an .m file or in the Contents.m file in a folder (pure text), and the formatted documentation of Matlab itself and its toolboxes, mainly kept as html and displayed in the embedded browser. Don't know how to integrate this into vim though.

Comment: The text based help from .m files would be enough. So Vim has to be configured to call Matlab with a script that calls the specified help and somehow passes it back to Vim. Maybe I can get that to work :-)

Comment: I think it might be easier to do this with a call to [sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html). Read lines of the m-file until the first that starts with `%`, for this and each following line that starts with `%` discard that `%` and possibly a following ` ` and print the rest, continue until the next line that does not start with `%`. I'm not an expert in sed, but I'm sure someone on SO can help you figure that out.